# Is possible to use sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier into a tensorflow Session i.e with Tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn

I am trying to use the KNN classifier inside a Tensorflow session.

But I am getting the following error:

`NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (Const:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported`

Outside the session the code works just fine:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
features= tf.constant([[1., 1.], [2., 2.],[2., 2.],[2., 2.],[2., 2.],[2., 2.]])
label= tf.constant([[1], [2], [2], [2], [2], [2]])
model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)

# Train the model using the training sets
model.fit(features,label)

teste = tf.constant([[1., 1.], [2., 2.]])
#Predict Output
predicted= model.predict(teste) # 0:Overcast, 2:Mild
print(predicted)
```

But I need it inside the Session, here is a code with example of the error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
@tf.function
def add():
    model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)


    features= tf.constant([[1., 1.], [2., 2.],[2., 2.],[2., 2.],[2., 2.],[2., 2.]])
    label= tf.constant([[1], [2], [2], [2], [2], [2]])
    # Train the model using the training sets
    model.fit(features,label)
    
    return model

add()
```

Versions :

```
tf.version.VERSION
'2.6.0'
sklearn.__version__
1.0.1
```

Comment: Can you try updating the numpy using `pip install numpy --upgrade`?

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\vitorbds\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\manntis_2\lib\site-packages (1.22.3)

Comment: My version is 1.22.3

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: Python 3.6.9  . The code work for u ? Into the session ?

Comment: I am trying to make it work. I will let you know if I the code works.

Comment: Does the answer helps you? If yes, can you please accept the answer as the solve of this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Yes !  thank you . I try ,but i dont know how accpet the ansewr , So i vote in ur ansewr .

Comment: I find it now , god  this button  should be more visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code may help you solve your problem.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)
@tf.function
def add():
    
    model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)


    features= tf.constant([[1., 1.], [2., 2.],[2., 2.],[2., 2.],[2., 2.],[2., 2.]])
    label= tf.constant([[1], [2], [2], [2], [2], [2]])
    features = features.numpy()
    label = label.numpy()
    # Train the model using the training sets
    model.fit(features,label)
    
    return model

add()
```

I have run the code in Google Colab. Downgraded NumPy to `1.19.5`

Note:

- `.numpy()` changes the tensor to numpy array.
- Tensorflow 2 has a config option to run functions "eagerly" which will enable getting Tensor values via `.numpy()` method. `3rd line of the code` [Without that line, the `.numpy()` will not work since `@tf.function` decorator prohibits the execution of functions like `tensor.numpy()` for performance reasons.